# Content Search Web Part Missing Item Options

Tags: search, content-query-web-part, content

I've add a content search web part on my site to search out tasks assigned to the person logged in. Essentially showing all tasks assigned to the user throughout the site collection on the home page. Works great but I can't change the  the Item to show only "Two lines" under the Display Templates:

[image]

It should be showing all these options:

[image]

Anybody have any ideas why I'm only showing two options and not all the options?

Comment: I came up with a work-around. As I pointed out in the comments to Unnie below, I am able to use the Content Search on one of our site collections but not on our main portal. So I created the Content Search Query on a site collection page with all the proper settings, then downloaded it to my desktop. Then I was able to upload it to our main portal page and it works. The odd thing is, that in the Item drop down it now shows just the three options, the original two shown above, and it added the Two lines that I used in the query! But it still doesn't show the other 4 options.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether these display templates are present in the **MasterPage Gallery** inside **Display Templates** -->**Content WebParts**.
2. If they exist, then select the Item template html--> Click View Properties --> Check **Target Control Type (Search)** property has **Content Web Parts** selected. If not edit the properties and select it.

Comment: Unnie - thanks for your reply. Yes the Target Control Type (Search) does have the Content Web Parts.

Comment: This is only happening on our main portal. If I try to set this up on another site collection, all the options are present!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the Master Page Gallery for the site collection with the issue has the correct content types applied.  Content types applied can be viewed in library settings.  JavaScript Display Template content type missing would likely cause this issue.  If not that content type, compare to a master page gallery on a site collection that is working.

I found that for some site collections I had to delete the current HTML and JS files and then copy the HTML files from a working site collection.  This prompted creation of new JS files and got things working.